# What are some advanced uses for Block?

Tags: scoping, coding-style

I read the answers to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/559/what-are-the-use-cases-for-different-scoping-constructs) (*What are the use cases for different scoping constructs?*) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7596460/condition-block-module-which-way-is-the-most-memory-and-computationally-effi/7597238#7597238) (*Condition, Block, Module - which way is the most memory and computationally efficient?*).

According to those, `Block` is safer (if something aborts, it restores the values) and [faster](http://blog.wolfram.com/2011/12/07/10-tips-for-writing-fast-mathematica-code/) (perhaps something to do with the low-level pointer redirection that I believe it uses) than `Module`, but less memory-efficient if the function is [defined a certain way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7596460/condition-block-module-which-way-is-the-most-memory-and-computationally-effi/7597238#7597238).

That being said, (1) why does Leonid say that `Module` is ["safer"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7596460/condition-block-module-which-way-is-the-most-memory-and-computationally-effi/7597238#7597238) when it doesn't have as-good garbage collection, and (2) if I am to use `Module` for most of the time, what are some of the "advanced" uses which require `Block`?

Comment: With `Block[]`, you can localize changes to system constants, e.g. `Block[{$RecursionLimit = Infinity}, (* stuff *)]`; you can't do that with the other scoping methods.

Comment: For another perspective on temporal efficiency there is this question, http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8226/why-modules-with-no-variables/8228#8228.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

### Safety

`Module` is safer than `Block` because:

- It is a lexical scoping construct, which means that variable bindings are only tied to a specific piece of code. Variables outside that piece of code are never affected by these bindings.

  In contrast, `Block` basically binds a variable to a piece of execution stack, not a piece of code. Such bindings are much harder to understand and debug, since execution stack is not something carved in stone, it is dynamic and usually data-dependent.
- The way `Module` resolves variable collisions is such that the integrity of inner or outer level bindings is never broken (at least in theory - in practice the lexical scoping is emulated in Mathematica and can be broken, but let's say this is very unlikely to happen by itself).

  In contrast, nested `Block`-s will simply have the variable value be the one (re)defined most recently, and also those different `Block`-s can be in different functions - while nested `Module`-s normally are in one function.

Both these points lead to the same conclusion that code which uses `Block` is harder to understand and debug. Basically, it is almost the same as using global variables (which are however guaranteed to get back their values after `Block` executes).

### Advanced uses of `Block`

Probably the main one is to change the order of evaluation non-trivially, in a way not easily possible with other constructs. `Block`-ed functions or symbols forget what they were, and therefore evaluate to themselves. This often allows to alter the order of evaluation of expressions in non-trivial ways.

I will show a couple of examples.

#### Example: emulating `OptionValue`

Here is one, from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335897/mathematica-how-is-optionvalue-implemented/5336802#5336802): a possible emulation of `OptionValue`, which is one of the most magical parts of the pattern-matcher:

```
Module[{tried},
  Unprotect[SetDelayed];    
  SetDelayed[f_[args___, optpt : OptionsPattern[]], rhs_] /; 
    !FreeQ[Unevaluated[rhs], autoOptions[]] :=
     Block[{tried = True},
       f[args, optpt] :=  
         Block[{autoOptions}, autoOptions[] = Options[f]; rhs]] /; ! TrueQ[tried];
  Protect[SetDelayed];]
```

the usage:

```
Options[foo] = {bar -> 1};
foo[OptionsPattern[]] := autoOptions[]
foo[]


(* {bar -> 1}  *)
```

#### Villegas-Gayley trick of function's redefinition

```
(call:f[args___])/;!TrueQ[inF]:=
   Block[{inF=True},
     your code;
     call
   ]
```

allows you to inject your own code into another function and avoid infinite recursion. Very useful, both for user-defined and built-in functions

#### Safe memoization

```
fib[n_]:=
 Block[{fib},
   fib[0]=fib[1]=1;
   fib[k_]:= fib[k] = fib[k-1] + fib[k-2];
   fib[n]
 ]
```

The point here being that the memoized values will be cleared automatically at the end.

#### Making sure the program does not end up in an illegal state in case of `Abort`s or exceptions

```
a = 1; b = 2;
Block[{a = 3, b = 4},
   Abort[]
]
```

The point here is that the values of `a` and `b` are guaranteed to be not altered globally by code inside `Block`, whatever it is.

#### Change the order of evaluation, or change some function's properties

Comparison operators are not listable by default, but we can make them:

```
Block[{Greater},
  SetAttributes[Greater, Listable];
  Greater[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {5, 4, 3, 2, 1}]
]

(*  {False, False, False, True, True}  *)
```

#### Preventing premature evaluation

This is a generalization of the standard memoization idiom `f[x_]:=f[x] = ...`, which will work on arguments being arbitrary Mathematica expressions. The main problem here is to treat arguments containing patterns correctly, and avoid premature arguments evaluation. Block trick is used to avoid infinite recursion while implementing memoization.

```
ClearAll[calledBefore];
SetAttributes[calledBefore, HoldAll];
Module[{myHold},
   Attributes[myHold] = {HoldAll};
   calledBefore[args___] :=
     (
       Apply[Set,
         Append[
           Block[{calledBefore},
             Hold[Evaluate[calledBefore[Verbatim /@ myHold[args]]]
           ] /. myHold[x___] :> x
         ], True]];
       False
     )
]
```

`Block` is used here to prevent the premature evaluation of `calledBefore`. The difference between this version and naive one will show upon expressions involving patterns, such as this:

```
calledBefore[oneTimeRule[(head:RuleDelayed|Rule)[lhs_,rhs_]]]
calledBefore[oneTimeRule[(head:RuleDelayed|Rule)[lhs_,rhs_]]]

(*
  False
  True
*)
```

where the naive `f[x_]:=f[x]=...` idiom will give `False` both times.

#### Creating local environments

The following function allows you to evaluate some code under certain assumptions, by changing the `$Assumptions` variable locally. This is just a usual temporary changes to global variables expressed as a function.

```
ClearAll[computeUnderAssumptions];
SetAttributes[computeUnderAssumptions, HoldFirst];
computeUnderAssumptions[expr_, assumptions_List] := 
   Block[{$Assumptions = And[$Assumptions, Sequence @@ assumptions]}, 
       expr];
```

#### Local `UpValues`

This example came from a Mathgroup question, where I answered using `Block` trick.

The problem is as follows: one has two (or more) long lists stored in indexed variables, as follows:

```
sym[1] = RandomInteger[10^6, 10^6];
sym[2] = RandomInteger[10^6, 10^6]; 
sym[3] = ...
```

One has to perform a number of operations on them, but somehow knows (symbolically) that 
`Intersection[sym[1],sym[2]] == 42` (not true for the above lists, but this is for the sake of example). One would therefore like to avoid time-consuming computation

```
Intersection[sym[1],sym[2]];//AbsoluteTiming

(* 
   {0.3593750, Null}
*)
```

in such a case, and use that symbolic knowledge. The first attempt is to define a custom  function like this:

```
ClearAll[myIntersection];
Attributes[myIntersection] = {HoldAll};
myIntersection[sym[i_], sym[j_]] := 42;
myIntersection[x_, y_] := Intersection[x, y];
```

this uses the symbolic answer for `sym[_]` arguments and falls back to normal `Intersection` for all others. It has a `HoldAll` attribute to prevent premature evaluation of arguments. And it works in this case:

```
myIntersection[sym[1], sym[2]]

(* 42 *)
```

but not here:

```
a:=sym[1];
b:=sym[2];
myIntersection[a,b];//Timing

(*  {0.359,Null} *)
```

The point is that having given `myIntersection` the `HoldAll` attribute, we prevented it from match the `sym[_]` pattern for `a` and `b`, since it does not evaluate those and so does not know what they store, at the moment of the match. And without such capability, the utility of `myIntersection` is very limited.

So, here is the solution using `Block` trick to introduce local `UpValues`:

```
ClearAll[myIntersectionBetter];
Attributes[myIntersectionBetter] = {HoldAll};
myIntersectionBetter[args___] :=
   Block[{sym},
      sym /: Intersection[sym[a_], sym[b_]] := 42;
      Intersection[args]];
```

what this does is that it `Block`-s the values of `sym[1]`, `sym[2]` etc inside its body, and uses `UpValues` for `sym` to softly redefine `Intersection` for them. If the rule does not match, then the "normal" `Intersection` automatically comes into play after execution leaves `Block`. So now:

```
myIntersectionBetter[a,b]

(* 42 *)
```

This seems to be one of the cases where it would be rather hard to achieve the same result by other means. Local `UpValues` I find a generally useful technique, used it in a couple more situations where they also saved the day.

#### Enchanced encapsulation control

This will load the package but not add its context to the `$ContextPath`:

```
Block[{$ContextPath}, Needs[your-package]]
```

This will disable any global modifications that the package being loaded could make to a given symbol:

```
Block[{symbolInQuestion}, Needs[the-package]]
```

There are many more applications, `Block` is a very versatile device. For some more intricate ones, see e.g. [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2793/making-a-symbols-new-definitions-be-tried-before-all-previously-defined-ones/2795#2795) - which provides means for new defintions to be tried before the older ones - a feature which would be very hard to get by other means. I will add some more examples as they come to mind.

Comment: What exactly does `Block` do in the `noUsage` function?

Comment: WOw, again an amazing answer +1

Comment: Great answer... thanks for sharing!

Comment: Regarding the safe memory usage when defining functions, which was `fib` in your example, what's the danger of having all those extra `DownValues` for `fib`?  In fact, if I kept them, the next time I called `fib` it would be faster, right?  In other words, what is the use of constraining the self-made `DownValues` (`f[x_]:=f[x_]=...`) with `Block`?  Does it somehow cause a memory leak?

Comment: @VF1 This depends on the situation. Sometimes you want to keep them for future calls. Sometimes, however, they are only needed to speed up that single computation, and future calls are unlikely to hit the same arguments. In those cases, keeping these extra defs would just slow down the hash lookup and hog the memory, so they better be removed after the call. `Block` allows you to do that automatically. B.t.w., a long overdue here on SE question IMO (your main one I mean). Thanks for the accept.

Comment: @Rojo Actually, very good point - I don't remember now. That example was based on my past memories. I grabbed this code from some old notebook that I wrote for version 5, and I only remember that there was some reason. I have removed it for now, until I recall what was done there. It could be that I did a rewrite and it was actually  no longer doing anything useful. In any case, this shows that at least some folks read this pretty carefully, which is really good :-). I added an example on local `UpValues`,as a compensation of sorts :-).

Answer (score 14):

Briefly, `Block` allows you to temporarily change global definitions and functions in a way that `Module` does not.  This is both its strength and weakness.

If you use `Block[{x = 5}, (* stuff *)]` without realizing that something deep inside "stuff" relies on `x` you may break things.  On the other hand you can use this power intentionally to do some interesting things.

#### Change global settings

With a recursive definition for Fibonacci numbers:

```
f[0] = 0; f[1] = 1;
f[n_] := f[n] = f[n - 1] + f[n - 2]
```

We need a larger value for `$RecursionLimit` to get the 300th number in the series:

```
Block[{$RecursionLimit = 500}, f @ 300]
```

> 222232244629420445529739893461909967206666939096499764990979600

#### Change the meaning of built-in syntax

```
listSample := {12*12.5*13*13.5*14*14.5, 12*12.5*13*13.5*14*14.5};

Block[{Times = List}, listSample]
```

> ```
> {{12, 12.5, 13, 13.5, 14, 14.5},
>  {12, 12.5, 13, 13.5, 14, 14.5}}
> ```

[Additional example](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7882/121) (more advanced).

#### Change the behavior of some internal functions

One can use this method to `Save` only the direct definitions of `expr`, rather than also all linked definitions as is the default behavior:

```
Block[{FullDefinition = Definition},
  Save["filename.m", expr]
]
```

#### Temporarily clear definitions

```
x = 1; (* global definition *)

D[Sin[x], x] (* this now fails *)
```

> General::ivar: 1 is not a valid variable. >>

Solution:

```
Block[{x}, g[x_] = D[Sin[x], x]]
```

We now have the correct `Definition` for `g`:  `g[x_] = Cos[x]`

Comment: Are those really the only uses?  Everything you mentioned goes under "temporarily clear definitions" to me.

Comment: @VF1 What applications are you envisioning?  Those are pretty useful abilities IMHO.

Comment: I do not deny that your abilities are indeed useful.  But those were things that I already knew and ones that Leonid mentioned in his answer to my first linked question.  In that same answer, he alluded to other, "advanced," uses of `Block`.  I was thinking there would be something clever, like the use of `Module` for defining functions.

Comment: @VF1, they will all fall in temporarily clear definitions because that's what `Block` does. But there are very creative uses of temporarily clearing definitions, like the ones mentioned and others. They mentioned typical examples but when you get the hang of it, custom uses come naturally and you begin to feel that `Module` has nothing to do. Say you do a recursive function `f[n_]:=f1[f2[f3[f4[f[n-1]]]]]`, it may be the case that by changing it to `Block[{f}, f1...` you delay `f` evaluation and get a less deep recursion stack.

Comment: That example and others may fall in the category of using `Block` to control the evaluation of inner parts of some code, without having to actually modify or mess with the internals. And, knowing there's a way to do that can open up doors on how you wish to design your own code

Comment: @VF1 as an example, look at my [`BlockStream`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1604/52) function (after the edit).