# How can I rewrite this with NestList or FoldList?

Tags: function-construction, functional-style

The original code used `For`:

```
{x, y} = {1, 1};
For[i = 0, i < 5, i++,
  x = x + 2 y;
  y = y + 2 x;
  Print[{x, y}]
  ];
Clear["`*"]
```

I am trying to use `NestList` to replace `For`, but the result is not as I expected. How can I rewrite it?

```
func[{x_, y_}] := {x + 2 y, y + 2 x};
NestList[func, {1, 1}, 5]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that you forget that you assign something to x and use this!

```
func[{x_, y_}] := Module[{xx = x + 2 y}, {xx, y + 2 xx}];
NestList[func, {1, 1}, 5]
```

But when you think about this short snip of code a bit longer, then you see the following: First you set `x = x + 2 y` and then you use this value in the next line. Basically, we can show this by simple replacements. We start with the `{x,y}` in the `Print` statement and do the calculation backwards:

```
{x,y}
%/.y->y+2x
%/.x->x+2y
ExpandAll[%]
(*
Out[56]= {x,y}
Out[57]= {x, 2x+y}
Out[58]= {x+2y, y+2(x+2y)}
Out[59]= {x+2y, 2x+5y}
*)
```

The last output shows exactly what Artes used. What you could notice here is, that this simple linear transformation can easily be converted into matrix form

```
{{1, 2}, {2, 5}}.{x,y}
(* {x + 2 y, 2 x + 5 y} *)
```

With this, you can write your `NestList`, which is equivalent to the function of Artes very nicely

```
NestList[{{1, 2}, {2, 5}}.# &, {1, 1}, 5]
```

Answer (score 10):

Without `Module` :

```
f[{x_, y_}] := {x + 2 y, 2 x + 5 y}
NestList[ f, {1, 1}, 5]
```

> ```
>  {{1, 1}, {3, 7}, {17, 41}, {99, 239}, {577, 1393}, {3363, 8119}}
> ```

or exactly

```
NestList[f, {1, 1}, 5] // Rest // Column
```

`Module` is not recommended when we encounter a long list (or deep nesting) see e.g. [Why modules with no variables ?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8226/why-modules-with-no-variables).

Answer (score 3):

In fact, even `NestList[]` is not needed, since *Mathematica* has `MatrixPower[]`:

```
NestList[{{1, 2}, {2, 5}}.# &, {1, 1}, 5]
   {{1, 1}, {3, 7}, {17, 41}, {99, 239}, {577, 1393}, {3363, 8119}}

Table[MatrixPower[{{1, 2}, {2, 5}}, k, {1, 1}], {k, 0, 5}]
   {{1, 1}, {3, 7}, {17, 41}, {99, 239}, {577, 1393}, {3363, 8119}}
```

`MatrixPower[]` can even be used to obtain a nice closed form for your iterates:

```
c[k_] = FullSimplify[MatrixPower[{{1, 2}, {2, 5}}, k, {1, 1}]]
   {1/2 ((3 - 2 Sqrt[2])^k + (3 + 2 Sqrt[2])^k), 
    1/2 (-(3 - 2 Sqrt[2])^k (-1 + Sqrt[2]) + (1 + Sqrt[2]) (3 + 2 Sqrt[2])^k)}
```

though this closed form does not automatically produce integers for integer argument, unless given some assistance:

```
c /@ Range[0, 5] // RootReduce
   {{1, 1}, {3, 7}, {17, 41}, {99, 239}, {577, 1393}, {3363, 8119}}
```