# Passing function as argument

Tags: function-construction, code-review

I've been mucking around with passing functions as arguments to other functions and via trial and error seem to have something that works. I was wondering if someone could have a quick look at some simple example code and let me know if this method is sound or if there are some things that I am overlooking.

Cheers...

```
Clear[mother];
mother[] :=
 Module[{f},
  f[x_, y_, z_] := x + y + z;
  child[f]
]

Clear[child];
child[functionArgument_] :=
  Module[{},
   functionArgument[1, 2, 3]
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not explain (at least to my satisfaction) what this code it supposed to do therefore is hard to give a rigorous answer, but I will attempt to cover multiple issues.

First a note: `Module[{}, . . . ]` is arguably a purposeless construct, one I have no use for and which I remove with every opportunity I get.  However at least one very experienced user [likes this construct](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8227/121) as a kind of tag signifying code with side-effects, though personally I find the idea of adding superfluous code as a form of comment disturbing.

### Interpretation

If I understand your question it can be restated as the idea of using this to generate a function:

```
make[] :=
  With[{r = RandomInteger[99]},
    Module[{f}, f[x_, y_, z_] := x + y + z + r; f]
  ]

make[]
```

> ```
> f$615
> ```

```
Definition[ f$615 ]
```

> ```
> Attributes[f$615] = {Temporary}
>
> f$615[x$_, y$_, z$_] := x$ + y$ + z$ + 92
> ```

If so the answer is yes, this is a common and effective method to create functions.

- The Symbol produced (here `f$691`) is unique within the kernel session and may be freely reused during that session, but saving and reloading this definition in another session could cause a collision.

### Alternatives

There are at least two alternatives to the pattern shown above.  The first uses [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Function.html):

```
make2[] := With[{r = RandomInteger[99]}, Function[{x, y, z}, x + y + z + r]]

make2[]
```

> ```
> Function[{x$, y$, z$}, x$ + y$ + z$ + 47]
> ```

This has an advantage over the `Module`-defined function: the anonymous Function can be copied, modified, saved and loaded at will.

It also has an important disadvantage: `Function` has no pattern matching control.  While you can use patterns *inside* the `Function` to perform different operations on different structures you cannot use pattern to prevent the application entirely, leaving the expression unevaluated.

The solution is a construct like the one that jVincent showed here:

- [Mathematica Destructuring](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8382/mathematica-destructuring/9759#9759)

Example:

```
SetAttributes[dFunction, HoldAll]
dFunction[pattern_, body_][arg___] /; MatchQ[{arg}, pattern] := {arg} /. pattern :> body

make3[] := With[{r = RandomInteger[99]}, dFunction[{x_?NumericQ, y_, z_}, x + y + z + r]]

fn = make3[]
```

> ```
> dFunction[{x_?NumericQ, y_, z_}, x + y + z + 86]
> ```

Now our function will only be applied if its arguments match the given pattern:

```
fn["foo", 1, 2]
```

> ```
> dFunction[{x_?NumericQ, y_, z_}, x + y + z + 86]["foo", 1, 2]
> ```

```
fn[Pi, 1, 2]
```

> ```
> 89 + π
> ```

Note that there is no (additional) definition to the Symbol `dFunction`.  You can copy, modify, save and load the expression `dFunction[{x_?NumericQ, y_, z_}, x + y + z + 86]` just as you would a `Function` so long as you first load the primary definition of `dFunction`.

Comment: I was looking at your example demonstrating the memory leak but found that when I ran "Names["f$*"]" all that returned was an empty list.(?) Anyway, the extensive answer was appreciated.

Comment: @Freakalien  Good catch.  I knew that `Module` sometimes leaked and I saw the extra Symbols when I was preparing my answer so I included that warning.  At the time I thought it must be due to interaction with `child` but I didn't explore it further.  However a very simple `Do[Module[{foo}, foo[x_] := 1; 0], {10}]` also leaks and it did not used to do that.  I am using version 10.0.0.  I just confirmed that neither the example in this comment nor `mother[]` leaks in version 7.  I suspect this is a bug in garbage collection; it deserves further scrutiny.

Comment: @Freakalien Failure of garage collection in the given example is a bug in version 10.0.0.  See: [(58375)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/58375)  I shall remove those statements from my answer.

Comment: I have V9.0.1.0 - glad I didn't upgrade!

Comment: @Freakalien FYI that leak has been fixed in 10.0.1.  You might consider upgrading, but personally I would wait for 10.0.2, unless you have need of the new functionality.