# Is garbage collection broken in version 10.0.0?

Tags: bugs, variable-definitions, scoping, symbols

**Bug introduced in 10.0.0 and fixed in 10.0.1**

---

In version 10.0.0 under Windows I am observing the following behavior:

```
Do[Module[{foo}, foo[x_] := 1; foo[0]], {10}]

Names["foo$*"]
```

> ```
> {"foo$593", "foo$594", "foo$595", "foo$596", "foo$597", "foo$598",
>  "foo$599", "foo$600", "foo$601", "foo$602"}
> ```

I am aware that in past versions `Module` Symbols were sometimes not garbage collected but never in such a simple case as this as far as I know.  The code above returns `{}` in version 7, as one would expect.

Do I have something wrong with my configuration or is this behavior reproducible?
Assuming the latter is there an explanation for this other than a bug?

Comment: I get the same behavior on OS X 10.9 with Mathematica 10.0.0. Using Mathematica 9.0.1.0 I get an empty list.

Comment: That's a known bug.

Comment: The interesting question is if 10.0.0 is more buggy than 9.0.0 was. I rarely use 10.0.0. Both kernel and FrontEnd are inferior to 9.0.1 (where comparable). Of course there are some exciting new features in 10, but I just wait for 10.0.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This bug is fixed in **V10.0.1.0** but the behavior is different based on evaluation sequence. If both expressions are in a single cell you get the expected empty list:

```
Do[Module[{foo}, foo[x_] := 1; foo[0]], {100}];
Names["foo$*"]
```

> ```
> {}
> ```

If they are evaluated one at a time in different cells you get a single `foo$` symbol regardless of how many times the `Do` loop is evaluated:

```
Do[Module[{foo}, foo[x_] := 1; foo[0]], {1000}]
```

Then evaluate

```
Names["foo$*"]
```

you get

> ```
> {"foo$"}
> ```

Comment: I don't have 10.0.1 or _Mathematica_ with me now, but what you're describing doesn't seem unexpected. I think if you re-evaluate the top cell a second time, you should see `{"foo$"}` in the output.

Comment: @rm-rf. I don't see `{foo$}` no matter how many times I evaluate the first cell.

Comment: In MMa 8.0.4 in the both cases I get empty list `{}`.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov. Yeah, that's what you should get but somehow in 10.0.1 on Windows I don't. But on Linux it works fine.

Comment: Have you reported it?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov. No I haven't. I'm a little reluctant reporting bugs because all the bugs I reported after v10 was released, none of them was fixed in 10.0.1. Also, this was a bug we reported and it was obviously worked on, yet they didn't test it properly.

Comment: I just have checked in MMa 10.0.1 under Win7 x64 and get empty lists `{}` in the both cases. I restarted MMa, repeated everything again and got the same result. Are you under 32-bit or 64-bit version of Windows?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov. I'm on 64bit Windows. Both Windows 8.1 and Windows 10TP give the same result.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Empty lists in both cases for me also with v.10.0.2 and OS X 10.9.5