# Speed of ConvexHullMesh

Tags: performance-tuning, finite-element-method, computational-geometry

Pick $N$ random points on the surface of the sphere, then use `ConvexHullMesh[]` to  compute their convex hull. Empirically, this takes time quadratic time in $N,$ whereas the state of the art as of 1996 is $N \log  N.$ Is Mathematica  doing something extra, or is its algorithm just 18 years out of date?

In the interest of "politeness".

```
randpt[n_]:= Module[{prept = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 3]}, prept/Norm[prept]]
experiment[n_]:= ConvexHullMesh[Table[randpt[3], {n}]//AbsoluteTiming
```

**EDIT**
Here is the experimental data (the first element in each pair is the number of points, the second the AbsoluteTiming [this on a very fast Windows PC])

```
{{10000, 6.133357}, 
 {20000, 17.791034},
 {30000, 50.460951},
 {40000, 106.783207},
 {50000, 182.384594}}
```

This looks awfully quadratic to me. I point out that experiments for small $n$ are meaningless, since there is linear overhead, which has a none-too-small constant, so swamps the quadratic growth. $50000$ points is not that many (and certainly would be a modest number for any FEM mesh), so this is clearly a major performance bug.

**ANOTHER EDIT** for comparison purposes, I also installed qhull on the very same machine, and ran `qconvex` on 50000 cospherical random points. The running time was, umm, well, it started spewing output at me the moment I hit return, so I am seeing a roughly three order of magnitude speedup.

Comment: It would be polite to include your code in the question so that it's easier for other people to attempt to reproduce your observations. I tested on my end (v10, OS X) for $N=2, 4, 8, \ldots, 2^{14}, 2^{15}$, and it seems to behave subquadratically for up to $2^{13}\approx 16{,}000$ points, after which it becomes quadratic. Maybe it has an upper limit on working memory for the $N\log N$ algorithm, beyond which it switches to a quadratic time algorithm.

Comment: @RahulNarain I am not sure how this would be "polite", since the code is completely trivial, but ok.

Comment: It is trivial to open a door, but it's polite for me to hold it open for someone. Thanks for adding the code.

Comment: Can you show some code that backs your claim up?

Comment: @user21 Yes, watch this space...

Comment: @IgorRivin, you posted a list of lists with some numbers; 40000 appears twice. Why is it so hard to post the *exact* code you run? I am not saying what you say is not correct but you make it much harder to reproduce than it must.

Comment: @IgorRivin, could you run this and tell me how that performs? "Needs["TetGenLink`"]
experiment[n_] := 
 AbsoluteTiming[TetGenConvexHull[Table[randpt[3], {n}]];][[1]]
Table[{i, experiment[i]}, {i, 10000*{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}]"

Comment: @user21 I am not at the same computer now, but can certainly try on the macbook I am on.

Comment: @user21 Also sprach der MacBook Pro: {{10000, 1.407865}, {20000, 2.679615}, {30000, 3.890393}, {40000, 
  4.975892}, {50000, 6.142689}}

Comment: @user21 my conjecture is all of the time is spent in the communication overhead (otherwise, I am unable to explain either why TetGen is so much slower than qhull, or why the times are actually growing slightly sublinearly)

Comment: @IgorRivin, how exactly did you call qhull?

Comment: @user21 Do you mean "with what arguments"? Otherwise, I called it as a standalone program, though I believe the same effect can be achieved by using MATLink (since Matlab uses qhull internally, I believe).

Comment: @IgorRivin, I'd like to know how you generated the input for qhull, how you exported it, how you called it on the command line, with which opetions; everything I need to know to reproduce your claim.

Comment: @user21 rbox D3 50000 s | qconvex s

Comment: @user21 qconvex informs me that it took it 0.262secs to compute the hull.

Comment: I filed this as a suggestion for future improvement.

Comment: In version 13 I see `{{10000, 0.233783}, {20000, 0.489283}, {30000, 0.701157}, {40000, 0.952774}, {50000, 1.21516}}`

Answer (score 10):

It appears to be just as it should be here (v10.0.0 under Windows):

```
randpt[n_] := With[{prept = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 3]}, prept/Norm[prept]]

Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]

BenchmarkPlot[{ConvexHullMesh}, Table[randpt[3], {#}] &,
 "IncludeFits" -> True,
 TimeConstraint -> 30
]
```

[image]

---

Following your update I tried a plot with larger *n* values as indicated.  The result:

[image]

Indeed it seems there is an issue with scale.  I am not familiar with the algorithm so I don't know if this should be considered a designed trade-off or a bug.

Comment: `BenchmarkPlot`, who knew!

Comment: @Igor I first learned about it here: [(54865)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/54865)

Comment: @Igor By the way I used `With` here because for the time being `Module` has problems: [(58375)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/58375).  I don't know if it would have affected the results but I thought it best to eliminate that factor.

Comment: Thanks! Is the semantics of `With` exactly the same as `Module` (if yes, it is weird that it does not inherit `Module`'s bugs...)?

Comment: @Igor Please see: [What are the use cases for different scoping constructs?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/559) -- `With`, `Block`, and `Module` all have the same syntax but work in very different ways.  In this case the value of `prept` does not need to be changed therefore `With` is a better choice.

Comment: So, should the question be closed?

Comment: @Mark I'll wait to see if Igor can demonstrate a case with different apparent complexity.  p.s. I voted for your answer of course.

Comment: Ah, I see! I  tend to use `Module` as a replacement for the Scheme `let`, but most of the time `With` is, in fact, the right thing if you program in a functional style (as I tend to).

Comment: @MarkMcClure I don't understand your question - I realize that it was before my updates, but is your _a priori_ assumption that I am hallucinating? Just wondering...

Comment: @Mr.Wizard It is clearly a bug. In fact, if you look at Szabolcs' MATlink, the primary example for why you might want to link with MATLAB is Delaunay triangulation and its various off-shoots (like convex hull). It is a shame, since Mathematica's mesh primitives are quite nice to use, but this performance is not really acceptable.

Comment: @Igor Oliver's answer might change your mind about that.

Answer (score 9):

The best you may hope for is the speed of `TetGen` as that is the underlying engine of the convex hull computation. The increase of timing you see comes from the fact that a `MeshRegion` needs to check the consistency. You can switch that consistency check of for `ToBoundaryMesh` (and there are a few other checks you can switch off, please see the documentation for `ElementMesh` [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/ref/ElementMesh.html))

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
Needs["TetGenLink`"]
randpt[n_] := 
 With[{prept = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 3]}, 
  prept/Norm[prept]]

Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]

BenchmarkPlot[{ToBoundaryMesh[#, "CheckIntersections" -> False] &, 
  TetGenConvexHull}, Table[randpt[3], {#}] &, 100, 
 "IncludeFits" -> True, TimeConstraint -> 60]
```

[image]

TetGen is used for the convex hull computation. Unfortunately, TetGen will compute a Delaunay tetrahedralization and the hull will be extracted from that. That is why you see a speed discrepancy compared with 'qconvex'. This may change in a future version.

Answer (score 7):

Quadratic?

```
randpt[n_] := Module[{prept = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 3]}, 
  prept/Norm[prept]];
experiment[n_] := First[AbsoluteTiming[ConvexHullMesh[Table[randpt[3], {n}]];]];
ListPlot[experiment /@ Range[500]]
```

[image]

Comment: See the various edits to the original post...