# Output a symbol from Module or Block

Tags: function-construction, scoping, output

I have troubles to output an entire symbol, a function in this case, from a module or a block. For instance

```
 myf = Block[{f}, f[3] = 33; f[4] = 4; f]
```

Then I want to get the values of `f` from the module valorization, but I get

```
 In[531]:= myf[3]

 Out[531]= f(3)
```

instead I would like to get the value that I have put in the module, in this case `

```
 "desired behaviour"

 In[531]:= myf[3]

 Out[531]= 33
```

I might be asking a RTFM question, but I do not see it answered anywhere.
Thanks for your help,
Roberto

Answer (score 3):

This will probably be closed as a duplicate of either:

- [What are the use cases for different scoping constructs?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/559/121)
- [Passing function as argument](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/58336/121)

In the meantime the simple answer is that you need [`Module`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Module.html) rather than [`Block`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Block.html), because the former creates a new Symbol whereas the latter merely temporarily changes the value of Symbol.

```
myf = Module[{f}, f[3] = 33; f[4] = 4; f]
```

> ```
> f$1464
> ```

```
myf[3]
```

> ```
> 33
> ```

In the example `f$1464` is the new Symbol that was created by `Module`.