# Find all heads a function is defined on

Tags: variable-definitions, argument-patterns, meta-programming, data-types

So say I've got a function `g` defined as follows:

```
g[x_Integer] := x + 1
g[s_String] := s <> "!!!"
```

How would I write a function `GetHeads` such that `GetHeads[g] == {{Integer}, {String}}` (i.e. the function returns the heads of all groups of arguments g is defined on)?

Comment: You may start by `(DownValues@g)[[All, 1, 1, 1]]`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If your definitions are *exactly* like you show, every time, you can use belisarius's method, slightly refined:

```
g[x_Integer] := x + 1
g[s_String] := s <> "!!!"

(DownValues@g)[[All, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1]]
```

> ```
> {Integer, String}
> ```

However this is fragile in that it will fail if your definitions are different, e.g.:

```
g[r_ /; Head[r] === Real] := r + Pi

g[a_List?MatrixQ] := foo[a]

(DownValues@g)[[All, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1]]
```

> Part::partd: Part specification
>   {HoldPattern[g[x_Integer]]:>x+1,HoldPattern[g[s_String]]:>s<>!!!,HoldPattern[g[r_/;Head[<<1>>]===Real]]:>r+[Pi],HoldPattern[g[(a:Blank[<<1>>])?MatrixQ]]:>foo[a]}[[All,1,1,1,2,1]]
>   is longer than depth of object. >>

If your intent is a truly robust method you may need to actually evaluate the function to see if it "accepts" the argument, meaning that it evaluates to something other than itself.  If it is costly to run a full evaluation you can interrupt the process as soon as a rule match is found by using my `step` function from:

- [How do I evaluate only one step of an expression?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/334/how-do-i-evaluate-only-one-step-of-an-expression/1447#1447)

Please load that function then try:

```
step @ g[#] & /@ {1, "a", 2.5, 1/2, I + 2, {}} // InputForm
```

> ```
> {HoldForm[1 + 1], HoldForm[StringJoin["a", "!!!"]], 
>  HoldForm[2.5 + Pi], g[1/2], g[2 + I], g[{}]}
> ```

Note that the types that match partially evaluate and are held by `HoldForm`, whereas the ones that do not match return with head `g`.  You could therefore use something like:

```
SetAttributes[test, HoldFirst]

test[f_, expr_List] := If[MatchQ[step @ f[#], _HoldForm], Head@#, ## &[]] & /@ expr
```

Example:

```
test[g, {1, "a", 2.5, 1/2, I + 2, {}}]
```

> ```
> {Integer, String, Real}
> ```

This returns the heads of the arbitrary expressions for which a match is found.

Comment: Very nice and always thorough. +1

Answer (score 7):

This also works:

```
getHeads[g_] := DownValues[g][[All, 1, 1, 1]] /. Verbatim[Pattern][_, k_] :> k[[1]]
```

Then:

```
getHeads[g]
```

> ```
> {Integer, String}
> ```

Answer (score 5):

```
f[g_] := Cases[First[#], Verbatim[Blank][x_] :> x, ∞] & /@ DownValues[g]
```

Comment: @kocho do not accept so fast :) it is good habit to wait a day or two. don't discourage others. p.s. This is not very general answer, you may want to consider `BlankSequence` e.g. Depeds what you need at the end :)

Comment: How would I extend this to work with anonymous functions?  Say I wanted to run `f[Function[x_Integer,x+1]]` and get `{{Integer}}`, is there any way to do that?

Comment: @kocho your use of `Function` is malformed.  `Function` does not accept parameter patterns.  If you need that look at [(9759)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9759) and the example [(58341)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/58341)