# What does empty {} mean in Module?

Tags: functions, programming, scoping

I have a question. I would like to know what an empty list (`{}`) means when used in `Module[]` as the code below shows? Why has a variable not been put inside `{}`?

```
Test[x_] := 
  Module[{},
    If[NumberQ[N[x]] && Not[ Head[N[x]] === Complex],
       True,(* then *)  
       False(* else *)   
    ]
  ]
```

Comment: It means there are no local variables defined.

Comment: [Duplicate](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8226/5467)

Answer (score 15):

Usually, when one defines a function that's not too complex (usually a one-liner) it is customary (here we mean *Mathematica* custom) to define it directly without any scoping constructs (`Module`, `With` or `Block`). For example:

```
myFunction[x_]:= 2 Sin[x] + Exp[-x^2]
```

But as the function definition gets more complex, instead of polluting the `Global` context with temporary variables, we use one of the scoping constructs mentioned above.

```
myModuleFunction[x_Integer]:= 
  Module[{pts, cvx},
    pts = RandomReal[4, {x, 3}];
    cvx = ConvexHullMesh @ pts;
    HighlightMesh[cvx, {Style[1, Black], Style[2, Yellow]}]
  ]
```

But sometimes a non-customary way is to use `CompoundExpression`s like the following shows:

```
myCompoundFunction[x_Integer]:= 
  (pts = RandomReal[4, {x, 3}];
   cvx = ConvexHullMesh @ pts;
   HighlightMesh[cvx, {Style[1, Black], Style[2, Yellow]}]
  )
```

Of course, in this scenario, both `pts` and `cvx` are now `Global` variables, so if you need to use them for further calculations outside the function's scope, they're available to you whereas, in the `Module` case above they aren't because we made them local. You can make those variables global using `Module` and this is where we answer your question:

```
myModuleFunctionGlobal[x_Integer]:= 
  Module[{},
    pts = RandomReal[4, {x, 3}];
    cvx = ConvexHullMesh @ pts;
    HighlightMesh[cvx, {Style[1, Black], Style[2, Yellow]}]
  ]
```

By not putting symbols defined in the body of `Module` into the module list, the symbols become global variables. Your function as defined doesn't really need a `Module` as it's just a simple `If` statement.

Comment: Might consider rewording "By using {}, any new variable defined therein becomes a global variable", it could be read as the empty list argument to `Module` is somehow needed, where I think something like "By *not* putting symbols defined in the body into the module list, they will be Global, perhaps unintentionally" is a bit more clear. +1, o/c...

Comment: @ciao. Good point, thanks. I've re-worded it as you advised.

Comment: Is there any difference in using the `global module function` approach over the `compound function`, or just personal preference?

Comment: In general, I used the `myModuleFunction[]` construction. BTW, what's the difference between `myCompoundFunction[]` and  `myModuleFunctionGlobal[]`? I think they are not good habit in *Mathemaica* programming.

Comment: @shrx I can't think of any difference between those two approaches, except maybe performance-wise, `myCompoundFunction` might be slightly faster.

Comment: @ShutaoTANG I agree those are not good habits. Personally, I use the `myModuleFunction` approach.

Answer (score 0):

Local variables will be put in the first `{}` in `Module[]`, for example:

```
f[x_] := Module[{}, t = x^2];
f[2]      (*--> 4*)
t         (*--> 4*)
```

You will obtain `t=4` after you evaluate the codes above, and if you

```
f[x_] := Module[{t}, t = x^2];
f[2]      (*--> 4*)
t
```

you will obtain t itself. Namely, `t` is just a *global symbol*(don't forget clear value of `t` before you evaluate)

which means the value of variables in the first `{}` of `Module[]` will be clear outside the `Module[]` if the variables were assigned in `Module[]`.

For you codes, there is no variable assigned so that there is nothing in the `{}`.