# What use is empty binding list in `Block[{},...]`?

Tags: core-language, scoping

[Spelunking](//github.com/szhorvat/Spelunking) the [`Export`](//reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Export.html) function, I stumbled upon the following definition:

```
Export[channel_File, expr_, format_List, opts___?OptionQ] := 
  Block[{}, 
    Message[Export::chtype, channel];
    $Failed
  ]
```

What is the point of using the [`Block`](//reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block.html) with an empty list of bindings? How is it different from just writing the body of the Block directly?

Comment: possible duplicate: [Why modules with no variables?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8226/34893) and links therein.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform: possibly, thanks. Not sure if Block has some subtleties though.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain the downvote please? This has been a very user friendly community... I have been using MMA for years, and do not believe this question is so *obviously* unwarranted as to not even explain why it is a wrong question to ask, really.

Comment: @user6014: Maybe. But the `Module` is lexical and evaluated away, while the `Block` is not.

Comment: Well, the difference between lexical and dynamic scoping only matters if you have local variables, and the point here is that you don't. There is no difference between `Block[{}, body]` and `Module[{}, body]` because of this, they both return `body`. Also, I would think that a user like Leonid Shifrin, who answered the other question, and who if anybody would know, would have mentioned if there were uses cases for `Block[{}, body]` in his answer, he wouldn't just have skipped it. I think the author of `Export` simply prefers `Block` to `Module` with or without variables. It's his "default".

Comment: @C.E. Thanks, I agree, this is an entirely convincing case of an acceptable *ad verecundiam Leonidi*! :) I'm accepting my question as a duplicate (there is a new button for that, never seen it before).

Comment: Sometimes I make a `Block` with no variables when I’m writing the skeleton of my function and I think I’m going to need to come back and populate it later. If I don’t end up needing it, I just keep it there. It doesn’t usually hurt performance and maybe I’ll still end up needing it.